# How to turn my website's authentication into a SAML Authentication provider?

Tags: php, authentication, saml

I am working with an existing legacy php authentication solution which works the following way:

1. Users put in their credentials
2. The code checks LDAP for authentication
3. If LDAP authentication is successful, the username is passed to a DB query to retrieve permissions
4. If LDAP authentication is not successful, the SQL DB is checked for authentication with the same credentials
5. If SQL Authentication is successful, the permissions are retrieved
6. If SQL Authentication is not successful, inform the user.

This is because many of our users are employees, and many are customers.

We now have a requirement from a secondary web provider to provide authentication via SAML.  The request is to turn our existing auth method into a SAML Auth source.  I've been experimenting with making a custom module in SimpleSAMLPhp but I'm not having any luck.  The documentation for configuring an external auth source like this is lacking, and my existing code essentially inputs POST variables as arguments, which I haven't been able to shoehorn together.  My difficulty in getting this to work is making me nervous about the overall security of the system if I did get it working.

What is a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From your question i have an impression that you are not very familiar with SAML protocol.

All i can do now is to give you some advices to get started.

First: Learn about protocol. Try to understand the SSO flow and differentiate which components in your company acts as "Service Provider" and "Identity Provider"

Second: Understand the scope of integration.Try to answer following questions:
- It's the application working in internal or external network ? 
- Who have the access? 
- Is there SAML authentication is already done for other applications in your company ?
- Is LDAP server is already controlled by Identity Provider, or you have to implement new one?

Once you get more familiar you can start thinking about development. There's many existing solutions and libraries available so once you get the concept of how protocol works it will be much easier to continue.

I will be happy to help you in your journey. This task will take you a lot of effort so be prepared.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that I'm not familiar, and I've been given 2 weeks to do this :)  We are a labor union.  1) The application is used externally AND internally.  Staff use it to manage users, non-staff union members use it to track recruits and questionnaires.  2) Access is determined by the results of the DB query, it's all laid out in there.  Authorization comes from successful LDAP OR SQL authentication, then specific permissions come from SQL. 3) LDAP is regular on-site AD and simplesamlphp has been tested off of it successfully...though we aren't using that.

Comment: IMO 2 weeks is a huge underestimation for this case. First of all you LDAP and AD must be connected to an application that acts as "Identity Provider" This will be an app that will handle requests and responses. If your company has already those, then it's barely possible to integrate php application. From what you wrote i can understand, there's no such integration yet.